# xslt string replace with substring-after

Tags: xslt, bi-publisher

I have a requirement to modify a field like :

`<ADDRESS>RieglerhÃtte|27|22|~|~</ADDRESS>` to `RieglerhÃtte 27/22`.

Remove all ~, replace all | to / (except first occurrence of | to ' ' space).

I tried using translate function as :

```
<?substring-before(ADDRESS,‘|‘)?> 
<?translate(translate(substring-after(ADDRESS,‘|‘),‘~|‘,‘/‘),‘|‘,‘/‘)?>
```

which is giving result as : `RieglerhÃtte 27///`

Also tried using replace :

```
<?xdofx:replace(replace(replace(ADDRESS,'~|',''),'|~',''),'|','/')?>
```

which works fine but doesn't have the space after first occurrence of | : `RieglerhÃtte/27`.
I tried using substring-before with replace but its giving error in BIP. (xdofx and xdoxslt cant be used together).

I am trying to get the output like `RieglerhÃtte 27` or `RieglerhÃtte 27/11/22/33` (for input as - `RieglerhÃtte|27|11|22|33`).

Comment: Do note that from your explanation (_"Remove all ~, replace all | to / (except first occurrence of | to ' ' space)."_) this `RieglerhÃtte|27|22|~|~` would be transformed into `RieglerhÃtte 27/22//`

Answer (score 0):

I think you were very close. Assuming `~` is your character for "blank", a `|` separates fields, and you don't want to show blank fields...

Try this:

```
<?substring-before(ADDRESS,‘|‘)?> 
<?translate(translate(substring-after(ADDRESS,‘|‘),‘|~‘,‘‘),‘|‘,‘/‘)?>
```

It first removes the blank values, and then changes the pipe separator to a forward slash.